# SQL combining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to fill in blank values in one table with values from another table, where a second value from each table matches. these are the two codes I have currently tried :

```
UPDATE pl_building 
    SET b.IPEDSNUM = (SELECT f.IPEDSID
        FROM pl_fulltextfinal as f
        WHERE b.INST = f.Uname
        AND CONVERT(INT, b.IPEDSNUM) < 1)
```

and

```
UPDATE pl_building
    SET b.IPEDSNUM = f.IPEDSID
FROM pl_fulltextfinal as f
INNER JOIN pl_building b
ON trim(b.INST) = ltrim(f.Uname)
WHERE CONVERT(INT, b.IPEDSNUM) < 1
```

Comment: Please try to format the sql statements.

Comment: Separated the two attempts into two boxes.

Comment: It would help if you would tell us what results you got from these two codes, and why it's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join to achieve this.. try below code.

```
UPDATE pl_building b
INNER JOIN pl_fulltextfinal f ON b.INST = f.Uname
SET b.IPEDSNUM = f.IPEDSID
WHERE CONVERT(INT, b.IPEDSNUM) < 1)
```

Comment: this results in this error, similar to what ive been encountering in other iterations of the code "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from pl_building b
join pl_fulltextfinal f
on b.INST = f.Uname
Where CONVERT(INT' at line 29"

Comment: @PierceLieberman sorry i didnt notice its for mysql..pls try my edited ans